# Parsing "的" as adjective suffix?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives

> 判断学校好坏的标准有很多，不过我认为老师的水平的最主要的。

I've interpreted above sentence as follows using ungrammatical English for reading Chinese with ease.

> Judging a school's good points and bad points 's criteria there are many, however I think that teachers level is the most important for sure.

The problem for me so far is the 2nd 的 which appears from the leftmost.

I've changed it into 是 instead so that I think the meaning of the sentence makes sense.

But actually the place takes 的. How should I interpret it??

Comment: Ahhh, after I reviewed the original sentence written in the book, 是 was used instead of 的。。。

Comment: Should I delete the post?

Comment: Actually, misreading is a common happened phenomenon for a new language learner including me (learning English). So in my opinion, leaving the post there is also useful (learners can be reminded to read carefully). Anyway, it's up to you.

Comment: @Havier I'll leave it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about writing:

判断学校好坏的标准有很多，
There are many ways to evaluate a school's quality,
不过我认为最重要的是老师教学水平的高低。
nonetheless, I believe, the quality of the teaching is most important.

Answer (score 1):

I had completely misread the originally given sentence.

The original sentence writes 是 at the place which I was focusing on.